# Automata Design software

Tags: open-source, finite-automata

I am looking for an ***open source*** GUI based application that can draw either FSM or Automata.
Anyone knows of anything?

Comment: I have designed a tool for FSM design. I appreciate it if anyone could help me with this: [link](http://mehr.sharif.edu/~h_mohajeri/activities/research/FSM/)

Answer (score 2):

I have looked into this many times over the years. My conclusion was you cant have open source + GUI and have it be functional.

The oss gui tools are usuall sub-par in some manner or another, generally they are out-of-date and unsupported.

There are many "build from a text file description" FSM generators out there. How badly do you really need the GUI.

If you meant *only draw* there are plenty, basically any OSS UML modeling tool should support drawing an FSM.

There are some commerial offerings that are good: Matlab, StateWorks.

For many years, the eclipse modeling framework - https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/ has looked promising - but i have never gotten anywhere with it

Answer (score 1):

I found [Fizzim](http://www.fizzim.com), an open source & GUI-driven app that can draw finite-state machines:

> The GUI is written in java for portability. The backend code
>   generation is written in perl for portability and ease of
>   modification.

It seems the latest version adds [Verilog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog) / [SystemVerilog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemVerilog) code generation.